# Powershell - Create folders and shares from a CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a repetitive task on Server 2012 R2 I'd love to automate. I have a CSV list of around 40 folder names I want to create (The names in this CSV changes). I then want to have those folders shared with the same name as the folder that is created. I also want to set full permissions for 3 local users on all folders.

I tried dabbling a bit with PowerShell but couldn't seem to get it going I think mainly because I was trying to use WMI to create the shares.. In the end I resorted to running the following and settings up the shares manually.

```
Set-Location "C:\test\" 
Import-Csv c:\test\folders.csv | New-Item -type directory
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: [A quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+share+folder), for me, shows two articles on the Scripting Guy's blog on how to do this very thing - [one for Windows 7/2008 R2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/16/how-to-use-powershell-to-create-shared-folders-in-windows-7.aspx), and [one for Windows 8/Server 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/09/powertip-use-powershell-to-create-new-shared-folder.aspx).  Setting permissions on a share with PowerShell is similarly easy to find with a search engine, as I recall.

Comment: This seems to me like a very legitimate question.  Not sure why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at [`Import-Module SMBShare`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635722.aspx) and use the [`New-SMBShare`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635722.aspx) cmdlet. You can do permissions with the [`Set-ACL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849810.aspx) cmdlet.

Combine them with your `Import-CSV` command on the pipeline and you shouldn't have any issues at all.